# Prove that if for all $g \in G$ that $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$, then we must have for all $g\in G$ that $gNg^{-1}=N$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I feel kind of shaky about this proof so I'd really appreciate some input. I know this is equivalent to some other forms (which I'll prove afterward so please don't spoil it). Here's the statement again:

> Prove that if for all $g \in G$ that $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$, then we must have for all $g\in G$ that $gNg^{-1}=N$.

**Attempt:** Assume $gNg^{-1}\subsetneq N$. Then $\exists gng^{-1}, gn'g^{-1} \in gNg^{-1}$ with $n\neq n'$ such that
$$gng^{-1}=gn'g^{-1}$$
but that implies $n=n'$, thus no such elements exist and $gNg^{-1}=N$.

Is this correct? I know I should've instead tried to show *if $n \in N$ then $n\in gNg^{-1}$* but this seemed to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $g \in G$. We know that $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$. We want to show that $$gNg^{-1} \supseteq N.$$

Let's just multiply this containment on the left by $g^{-1}$ and on the right by $g$ to get that we want to show $$N \supseteq g^{-1}Ng.$$

So, we just need to show that $g^{-1}Ng \subseteq N$. But we already know that for all $x \in G$ that $xNx^{-1} \subseteq N$. Hence let $x = \ldots$? (Once you know what to pick for $x$, you will have finished a proof.)

---

The way your attempt goes, I would instead say this: Assume $gNg^{-1} \subsetneq N$.  Thus there exists $n_0 \in N$ such that for all $n \in N$, $gng^{-1} \neq n_0$. But this can't actually be true because all we need to do is consider $n = g^{-1}n_0g$.

---

As can be seen in the comments below, I interpreted the 'for all' quantifier a little differently than what the OP originally wrote. Indeed, the statement as it was written does not hold for all infinite groups. Here is a counterexample:

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}[1/2] \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$. Let $(1,0)$ be a normal generator of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$, and let $(0,1)$ generate the $\mathbb{Z}$ on the right side of the semidirect product. Let $N = \langle (1,0) \rangle$. Notice that $N$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$. Indeed,  if we conjugate $N$ by $(0,1)$ we get $\langle (2,0) \rangle$, which is a proper subset of $N$. But if we conjugate $N$ by $(0,-1)$, then we get $\langle (1/2, 0) \rangle$, which is not a subset of $N$.

Comment: I don't think that's the assumption. I think the statement is "prove that for all $x \in G$, A implies B". This differs from "(for all $x$ $A$) implies B." Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Mr.Chip The way the question is worded, I agree, but then I'm not completely confident the statement is true for infinite groups. Hence, I interpreted the question as saying prove that "(for all $x$ $A$) implies B".

Comment: Yeah... Not sure. Your latest edit doesn't work btw because your final choice of $n$ need not be in $N$.

Comment: @Mr.Chip. Again I agree it isn't necessarily in $N$ if we interpret the question literally. However, I think the OP meant to write this: Prove that if for all $g \in G$ that $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$, then we must have for all $g \in G$ that $gNg^{-1} = N$. In other words if for all $g \in G$, $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$, then $N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Oh sure, sorry. Quite right, your edit is fine on the other interpretation.

Comment: I get it that from $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ if we set $g=g^{-1}$ then $g^{-1}Ng \subseteq N$. The problem I run into is the relying on $$gNg^{-1} \supseteq N \equiv N \supseteq g^{-1}Ng.$$ I'm currently proving a couple things are equivalent *to allow me to multiply like that*, so I feel like this answer would require me proving $$gNg^{-1} \supseteq N \iff N \supseteq g^{-1}Ng$$ first. Is this solution required?

Comment: Also, sorry about the wording of the question. You were correct with your interpretation Adam, I'll edit the title, thank you.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you do need to know that $gNg^{-1} \supseteq N \implies N \supseteq g^{-1}Ng$. This follows from the following more general statement: If $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $G$ and $x \in G$, then $A \subseteq B$ implies that $xA \subseteq xB$ and also that $Ax \subseteq Bx$.

Comment: Ahhh that's another one of the equivalences I need to show for this problem. [Here was the full problem.](https://i.imgur.com/Tg0Ynau.png) I suppose I should start with that equivalence first then, thank you for clearing things up!

Answer (score 2):

The statement is true for all groups, not just finite ones.  What you've written here is not well explained, it looks like you're showing that conjugation is injective and so it's a bijection.  But this style proof will only work when $N$ is finite.

Instead, what happens if you conjugate $N$ by $g^{-1}$ instead of $g$?

Comment: Sorry, but whats the meaning of conjugate here? I haven't heard the term before.

Comment: Conjugation by $g$ means to multiply by $g$ on the left and $g^{-1}$ on the right.  So if $h$ is an element then $ghg^{-1}$ is $h$ conjugated by $g$ and if $N$ is a subgroup then $gNg^{-1}$ is $N$ conjugated by $g$.